# Node server unable to retrive the value of react axios request header parameter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-headers, axios

I need to access axios header authorization token in server side(Node), showing undefined. Please help..

Client side(React) request:

```
var config = {
        headers: {
            'cache-control':'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'authorization' :'bearer '+Auth.getToken()
          }
      };
    axios.get(ApiConfig.API_BASE+'api/admin/profile/', config).then(function(response) {
      this.setState({status:'success', profile: response.data.data});
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Server side(Node):

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

console.log(req.headers.authorization); 

  if(!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).end();
  }
 };
```

Log showing undefined. I also console the entire header, but their output is:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8027',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,cache-control',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

How do I retrieve the authorization token value?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract request http headers from a request using NodeJS connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147693/how-to-extract-request-http-headers-from-a-request-using-nodejs-connect)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using express. If so, instead of getting the header value as `req.headers.authorization`, try `req.get('authorization')`.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get

Comment: Not working, console.log(req.header('authorization')); still showing undefined.

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Comment: version: express@4.15.4

Comment: @PriyabrataAtha I've updated the answer. Please check again

Answer (score -1):

If you are making a cross-origin HTTP request, please make sure CORS has been enabled in your server. If you are using express [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware can be used.

I guess your problem here is that since CORS has not been enabled, your server will receive a OPTIONS request first, so the entire header you console is from the OPTIONS request not the GET request as you desired. You can use `console.log(req.method)` to verify. BTW `req.headers.authorization` is ok to receive the header.

Comment: console.log(req.method); showing "OPTIONS" and req.headers.authorization still undefined.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your server?

Comment: Yes, this is my localhost. And I set                                                app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  next();
});