# Laravel Sanctum - Logged in user best practise

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I was wondering what is the best practise for checking that a user is still logged in client side.

Let's say a user logs in. If it's successfull it will be saved in the state, something like this:

```
axios.post('/login').then(() => {
  this.state.loggedInUser = true
});
```

Now if a user refreshes their browser, the state is lost, but the `laravel_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN` are still available and valid.

Would it make sense to add middleware on every page reload to make a request to retrieve the current logged in user's information? Something like this?:

```
const authMiddleware = () => {
  axios.get('/user').catch(() => console.error('user is not logged in!'));
};
```

**EDIT**

Please be aware that I'm using Sanctum in SPA mode. So there's no tokens.

Comment: Have you tried `serverMiddleware`? You can access `req.headers` to extract the session. It uses connect instance, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147693/how-to-extract-request-http-headers-from-a-request-using-nodejs-connect. It's also a best practice to always run tokens and other sensitive informations in the server.

Comment: For `serverMiddleware` reference: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Vue and Vuex for my SPA, I have managed to keep track of authenticated users using the setup below:

#### store.js

The store.js keeps track of the `user` and `isLoggedIn` state.

```
import { isLoggedIn } from "./utils";
export default {
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        user: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        },
        setLoggedIn(state, payload) {
            state.isLoggedIn = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async loadUser({ commit, dispatch }) {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                try {
                    const user = (await axios.get("/user")).data;
                    commit("setUser", user);
                    commit("setLoggedIn", true);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### utils.js

The utils.js contains helpers for setting and getting logged in state from local storage.

```
  
export function isLoggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") == "true";
}

export function logIn() {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
}
```

#### Login.vue

In the login.vue, i'm calling the `logIn()` from the utils.js to set the isLoggedIn value in LocalStorage.

Also, the `loadUser` action is being dispatched to set the user information in the Vuex store.

```
<script>
import { logIn } from "../utils";
 methods: {
        async login() {
            try {
                await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
                await axios.post("/login", {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                });
                logIn();
                this.$store.dispatch("loadUser");
                this.$router.push('/');
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### App.js

The `loadUser` action is also being dispatched here to make the user's information available globally if logged in.

```
const app = new Vue({
    ...
    async beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.dispatch("loadUser");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

store it in sessionStorage, and also initialize loggedInUser from sessionStorage as:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInUser') === 'true' || false
```