# Get access to headers in TypeScript when req is typed

Tags: typescript, express

I have a method which is typed with: `Express.Request`
How can I access headers within this method?

Example Code:

```
    private _onTokenReceived(req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response): void {
        const header: string = req.headers.authorization;
    }
```

In my example headers is not reachable.

```
Error: The "headers" property does not exist for the "Request" type.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302180/9123677) on stackoverflow, if you use Express 4.x, you can use the `req.get(headerName)` method as described in Express 4.x API Reference.